# Marketo API - How to extract data based on createdAt

Tags: node.js, marketo

I need list the Email object within some date range , how to get it through marketo API?

I'm working with marketo API and I need to get the emails which are created between some date. I know the response will have `createdAt`, how can I query it while making the API call itself?

I tried this,

`/rest/asset/v1/createdAtGreaterThan=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z   &createdAtLessThan=2023-01-31T23:59:59Z`

Also is there a way I can sort this result?